# javascript alert when element is visible

Tags: jquery, visible

i have the following code:

```
var blink1 = function() {
    $('.leftArrowMask').hide();
    setTimeout(blink2, 5000);
};
var blink2 = function() {
    $('.leftArrowMask').show();
    setTimeout(blink1, 1000);
};
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(blink1, 1000);
});
```

this basically shows a div for 1 second, and then hides it for 5 seconds.

I would like to display an alert everytime the div is visible.

i have tried the following but it doesnt seem to work:

```
function checkVisibility(){
  if ($('.leftArrowMask').is (':visible') && $('.leftArrowMask').parents (':hidden').length == 0)
  alert ("Visible!");
   setTimeout('checkVisibility',1000)//every 1 second...
}
```

any ideas on what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var blink1 = function () {
        $('.leftArrowMask').hide();
        setTimeout(blink2, 5000);
    };
    var blink2 = function () {
        $('.leftArrowMask').show();
        setTimeout(blink1, 1000);
    };
    $(document).ready(function () {

        setInterval(function () {
            if ($('.leftArrowMask').is(':visible') && $('.leftArrowMask').parents(':hidden').length == 0) {
                alert("Visible!");
            }
            setTimeout(blink1, 1000);
        }, 1000);

        //
    });
```

See [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dubeynee/PgzrU/55/)

Hope helps

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout('checkVisibility',1000)//every 1 second...
```

This is wrong, remove single quotes (')

```
setTimeout(checkVisibility,1000);
```

Comment: i have removed the single quotes and still not alerting?

Comment: I think it is also nessecary to add the open and close braces

Comment: `if (($('.leftArrowMask').is (':visible')) && ($('.leftArrowMask').parents (':hidden').length == 0))` maybe this too.  Also where are you calling this `checkVisibility` method?

Answer (score 0):

You could only set a setInterval somewhere in your code.

```
setInterval(function() {
    if ($('.leftArrowMask').is (':visible') && $('.leftArrowMask').parents (':hidden').length == 0) {
        alert ("Visible!");
    }
}, 1000);
```